# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver

Tags: selenium, jenkins, centos

I am getting following error when I am trying to execute my automated test cases via Jenkins.

```
Server Using: Centos 7
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /usr/local/bin/geckodriver

While checking the server I found geckodriver and chromedriver already exist on the path "/usr/local/bin/" but I still don't know why Jenkins is throwing these errors.

I also check the access and privileges for geckodriver and chromedriver both are set to 777. Both geckodriver and chromedriver are downloaded/installed correctly.

Comment: Can you update the question with your code trials and error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

From your Jenkins script try running a simple shell script like:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```

and see the result you get.

Comment: I already did that but still it was returning the same error. I believe there is some problem with the installation of Jenkins

Comment: How did you install Jenkins?

Comment: @Cœur sorry about that